# No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"blogs"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller

I'm doing something silly wrong here, but I can't figure what is it.

In my view I have the following code:

```
- if current_page?(edit_blog_path)
```

That I use to show some page specific features in the page.

this causes the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError - No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"blogs"}:
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:540:in `raise_routing_error'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:536:in `rescue in generate'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:528:in `generate'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:569:in `generate'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:594:in `url_for'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:148:in `url_for'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:107:in `url_for'
```

my rake routes says:

```
 % rake routes | grep blog
              blogs GET    /blogs(.:format)                 blogs#index
                     POST   /blogs(.:format)                 blogs#create
           new_blog GET    /blogs/new(.:format)             blogs#new
          edit_blog GET    /blogs/:id/edit(.:format)        blogs#edit
               blog GET    /blogs/:id(.:format)             blogs#show
                     PUT    /blogs/:id(.:format)             blogs#update
                     DELETE /blogs/:id(.:format)             blogs#destroy
          blogs_new POST   /blogs/new(.:format)             blogs#new
                     GET    /blogs/:id/next(.:format)        blogs#next
                     GET    /blogs/:id/previous(.:format)    blogs#previous
           user_root GET    /blog/root(.:format)             blogs#root
```

any clue??

thanks.

Comment: Post the `view code`,where you are using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`edit_blog_path` requires a blog as argument.

`edit_blog_path(@blog)` for example.

If you just want to check, whether you are at an edit_blog page, without caring which blog is being edited, you can do something like this.

```
if controller_name == 'blogs' && action_name == 'edit'
```

If you just want to distinct between new and edit forms you can also do

```
if @blog.persisted?
  # existing blog
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? The answer is correct, though maybe not as thorough as some other answers.

Comment: Not complete answer as you can pass `id` only

Comment: Not complete, but not incorrect either, so a downvote would not be in it's place here.

Comment: Thanks well spotted. though I'm using it to separate in the view the case when I'm generating a new blog from the case when I'm editing it. 

when I'm creating it the blog doesn't have an id yet, so I get still an error: `No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"trades", :id=>nil}`

Comment: the `persisted?` version doesn't work, my app doesn't know persisted? apparently

Comment: Strange, should be there since Rails 3.0 http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/persisted%3F

Answer (score 1):

You need do either pass `id` like

```
if current_page?(edit_blog_path(id: @blog.id))
```

or pass whole blog object like this

```
if current_page?(edit_blog_path(@blog))
```

Comment: Specifically, if you already have the `@blog` in memory, why would you pass the id ever when you can pass the object itself?  Im just curious, as the line is longer, and less PIE.  You are editing the `@blog`.  Sure it works, but I can't think of a particular use case for doing it this way.  Also, the above answers are complete as they answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the route helper edit_blog_path requires an id. Perhaps edit_blog_path(@blog) might work (or replace @blog with the variable that you have in there)?

Comment: Not complete answer as you can pass `id` only